# How to configure self-contained single-file program?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am experimenting with `.Net Core 3` trimmed single-file publishing creating a simple console application and using this to publish:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true
```

Configuration is done with the standard `appsettings.json` and `ConfigurationBuilder` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`.

The problem is the config file is packaged with the whole app and so is unavailable - it can be accessed in the temp dir created when running the program but that is not very useful for a regular user.

I found out that you can exclude files from the packaging process by editing the csproj file or with a custom publishing profile

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

This does output the appsettings file in the publish dir however it is not used when running the application - an empty config file is created and used instead. Is there any way to do this "properly" since documentation is kinda lacking on the issue or should I just manually parse the file I expect to be in the starting directory (which itself was a hassle to find because `Assembly.Get###Assembly` were all returning the temp dir)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that adding this to the ConfigurationBuilder() before the AddJsonFile() seems to do the trick:

```
   .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
```

i.e.:

```
var configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: false)
        .Build();
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I needed. It's even simpler than the way I used to get the dir before:
`Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`